# SQL dynamic where clause based on parent table column

Tags: sql, db2

I've the below two tables and need a single SQL with these requirements (no `UNION`).

If `CHECK_CHILD` is `FALSE`, then just return rows from Parent table.
If `CHECK_CHILD` is `TRUE`, then check if there is a reference row in CHILD table and return PARENT row.  If there is no reference row in CHILD table, then don't return PARENT row.

```
  PARENT Table
  ID           INT (PK)
  CHECK_CHILD  BOOLEAN

  CHILD TABLE
  ID          INT (PK)
  PARENT_ID   INT (FK)
```

Sample Data:

```
    PARENT Table
    ------------
    ID    CHECK_CHILD
    1     FALSE
    2     TRUE
    3     TRUE

    CHILD Table
    -----------
    ID    PARENT_ID
    1     2
```

With this sample data, the query should return first two rows from the PARENT table because third row doesn't have reference row in the CHILD table.

Comment: Look at the `CASE WHEN` statement and see if that fits your needs?

Comment: Add some sample table data, and the expected result!

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - DB2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of alternatives:

```
select P.* 
from PARENT P
left outer join CHILD C
  on C.PARENT_ID = P.ID
where P.CHECK_CHILD = 'FALSE'
   or C.PARENT_ID is not null
```

or

```
select * 
from PARENT P
where P.CHECK_CHILD = 'FALSE'
   or (
    P.CHECK_CHILD = 'TRUE' 
    and exists (select 1 from CHILD C where C.PARENT_ID = P.ID)
   )
```

Comment: Thank you @mustaccio , the second logic is easy and it works fine.